Leaked Google OAuth refresh tokens
I am getting this warning on google play console: Leaked Google OAuth refresh tokens, Your app embeds Google OAuth refresh tokens which is not recommended
How can I detect which part of my code has this embedded token? Is there a tool to detect it?

Seems like you have an hard coded oAuth token embedded in your app which is a security risk: https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7052200?hl=en To check your app I would open it in a decompiler like Jadx-GUI and search for "refresh" or similar strings.

@Robert I wonder whether any static code analysis tools detect it.

Google used different tokens, one token type hat has a very long validity always starts with the text aas_et/ - that would be the only string I know you could search for. Some other token type always starts with ya29..
